# Flask allows multiple server instances to listen on the same port

Tags: python, flask, server

I have been using flask and noticed this unusual behavior.

My flask application is set to run on port 5000 in my machine (It has only one network card).

When I attempt to start more than one instance of the same flask application in my machine.

**What I Expected**:

A port address in use error when attempting to start the next instance bound on the same port.

**What actually happened**:

They all start successfully and bind to the same port. This kind of behavior is not expected with most conventional servers that I have used.
Thankfully however, only one process out of the 'n' processes is triggered when a REST API call is made to the server.

Operating System: Windows

Can someone please explain why this behavior occurs, and how can I ensure that flask doesn't start the process successfully in such a case.

netstat -aon | find "5000"

TCP    127.0.0.1:5000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       37036
TCP    127.0.0.1:5000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5024
TCP    127.0.0.1:5000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       61684

The above are the 3 process that are running in parallel.

Additional Notes:

1. I am using this in a virtualenv.
2. The way I have written my flask invocation.

   ```
   if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
   app.run(port=5000)
   ```
3. Running the code as `python3 <filename>.py` at the command prompt.

Comment: How are you running your flask application?

Comment: if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    app.run(port=5000)

Comment: @GarbageCollector I have added the info in the question.

Comment: Using the development example? I have tested flask development server on windows, mac and linux and it _does_ throws _port already in use_ if i try to launch flask server multiple times without closing the already running server

Comment: +1 for observed OSError on linux with slightly different settings (debug is False), using flask 0.12.1, py 3.5.2

Comment: I set debug to False and tried it out once now too. Same behavior of allowing me to start the servers. Python 3.6.3 and Flask 0.12.2.

Comment: Can one of you show me how differently you are running your flask app? Will also check if this is an issue because of using venv.

Comment: Are you running a WSGI server?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin No, Iam not. Running it purely with flask.

Answer (score 5):

This is likely Windows specific behavior and how they manage sockets. On Windows, you can have multiple processes bind to the same port for listening. This was found to cause a lot of security issues, so Windows released updates that can prevent a port from being hi-jacked by another process via the SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE socket flag. You can read more about it at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/so-exclusiveaddruse

From what I can see by reading through the flask development server code, there is no way for a user to set the SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE flag.